# How to gradually unveil a tikz node from its background

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, transparency

I would like to gradually unveil a `tikz` `node` from its background (like an animation, from un-noticable to gradually clear). One strategy could be to gradually reduce the `opacity` level of the node, through a `foreach`. I am not sure if is the right approach as it is still rather discrete and non-smooth.

Comment: Animation? Do you want to do this in `beamer` (as part of overlays)? Or in `animate`? Or …?